# Make recipients field of Thunderbird just one line high

Tags: thunderbird

Whenever I compose a message in Thunderbird, there is room for four recipients, but I usually only use one. Is there some way to make this field smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Add-on:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/address-widget-lines/

Found the link in a Mozilla bug about this issue:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=425451